# CSS overflow-x: hidden makes certain elements move up and down on mobile device

Tags: html, css

Using   overflow-x: hidden; for the body and html results in a hyperlink button moving up and down the page when scrolling through that section on a mobile device.

CSS:

```css
.second_section_button {
      color: #ef4723;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 295px);
      padding: 25px 30px;
      margin: 40px 0;
      font-size: 24px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      letter-spacing: 2.5px;
      -webkit-box-reflect: below 1px linear-gradient(transparent, #0005);
}

HTML:

    <a href="#" class="second_section_button">
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
           ENTER NOW
         </a>
```

Comment: Can you please show us your HTML-Code?

Comment: <a href="#" class="second_section_button">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          ENTER NOW
        </a>

Answer (score 0):

A section further down had a height specified which was too low, adjusted this and the button higher up the page no longer moves on mobile.